# SQLAlchemy query the database and display to html form

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Working on flask web app and I have this working row SQL command to insert data to my database.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    cur = connection.cursor()
    employee_id = request.form['employee_id']
    emp_nums = {'1000': 'DEV', '1001': 'ANA'}
    if employee_id in emp_nums:
        print(employee_id)
        resultValue = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM employee_data WHERE team 
        = "{}"'''.format(emp_nums[employee_id]))
        if resultValue > 0:
            print(resultValue)
            userDetails = cur.fetchall()
            return 
            render_template('attendance.html',userDetails=userDetails)
        return render_template('login.html')
```

Am trying to modify this code to use SQLAlchemy but can't get the query result

```
@app.route('/attendance', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def attendance():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        o_id = request.form['o__id']
        emp_nums = {'1000': 'DEV', '1001': 'ANA'}
        team = emp_nums.get(o_id,'')
        print('team is',team)
        userDetails = Employee_data.query.filter_by(team = team).all()
        print(userDetails)
       return render_template('take_attendance.html', 
       userDetails=userDetails)
    return 'no data corresponding '
```

The above code returns nothing. Thank you for you help

Comment: Is this a Flask application by any chance? Google "The Flask mega tutorial" as there is a very popular guide. There is a section on how to use flask_sqlalchemy, an extension for flask which will make things much easier :)

Comment: Actually i just snip  this code section only to make it simple. and also i visit "The Flask Mega Tutorial" but i can't find how to get the value from the dict i defined.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. What does your `Employee_data` model look like? And what's the value of `team` in this case?

Comment: **Employee_data** model contains employee info and **team** value is a dict that defined above and i wanted to check its value with the value in the database and make the query.

Comment: I am sorry `team` here is of a `dict` type? can you show the output of the print statement?

Comment: **team** prints the value of the dict on the console.